# Why can't I push upgrade to certain orgs?

Tags: push-upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade all our customers to the newest version of our app. In the developer org for the app, I have upgraded all but a few orgs (for those orgs, the upgrade failed). However, I see many more orgs (a few thousand) in our LMA that have not been upgraded. Some of them are active production or sandbox orgs that have recently installed our app. But if I search for their org ID in the Push Upgrades section (e.g. click Push Upgrades > Schedule Push Upgrades > enter the newest version of the app > "Filter by Organization" under "Select Target Organizations") I don't see the org ID returned there.

I see that next to the "Version" picklist when scheduling a push upgrade, it says what versions are eligible to upgrade. The org I saw in the LMA is on a version eligible to upgrade, but does not show up in the Push Upgrades section. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you recently [refreshed license records in your LMA](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000318335&type=1)? Are you absolutely sure these missing package installations were not upgraded in the meantime? The LMA might just display obsolete data.

(It's a while ago since I've done mass upgrades of packages, but there is a lot of caching going on. It might be that you just need to wait a couple of hours.)

Comment: Hm, I hadn't tried refreshing the license records. Are you saying that's what I should do?

Comment: I checked the next day as well and those same orgs were missing. Many of them were sandbox orgs that had uninstalled our app, and the production orgs that were missing were our internal orgs, so we were okay, but it didn't address why the orgs didn't show up in the dev org for upgrading.

Comment: Yes, I would have refreshed the license records to make sure the LMA shows up-to-date data. But you seem to be sure that at least your internal orgs were definitely on old versions and the LMA reflects this. If so, - no idea.